# Angularjs Progress circle not working on dynamic input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

when I try to give input value to progress circle in Angular js, only the value(20%) is displayed and loader color is not shown. please refer the attached screenshot.

The Angular progress works fine if the input value(20%) is given directly given in HTML.
But when try to bind value{{count}} its showing only the value, but some css is missing and the progress color is not displayed.

**$scope.count= 20;**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.loading = function() {

        var backgroundColor = '#ccc';
        var progressColor = '#1abc9c';
        var percent = 90;
        var duration = 2000;

        var DEFAULTS = {
            backgroundColor : '#ccc',
            progressColor : '#1abc9c',
            percent : 90,
            duration : 2000
        };

        $(this)
                .each(
                        function() {
                            var $target = $(this);

                            var opts = {
                                backgroundColor : $target.data('color') ? $target
                                        .data('color').split(',')[0]
                                        : DEFAULTS.backgroundColor,
                                progressColor : $target.data('color') ? $target
                                        .data('color').split(',')[1]
                                        : DEFAULTS.progressColor,
                                percent : $target.data('percent') ? $target
                                        .data('percent') : DEFAULTS.percent,
                                duration : $target.data('duration') ? $target
                                        .data('duration') : DEFAULTS.duration
                            };
                            // console.log(opts);

                            $target
                                    .append('<div class="background"></div><div class="rotate"></div><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div><div class=""><span>'
                                            + opts.percent + '%</span></div>');

                            $target.find('.background').css('background-color',
                                    opts.backgroundColor);
                            $target.find('.left').css('background-color',
                                    opts.backgroundColor);
                            $target.find('.rotate').css('background-color',
                                    opts.progressColor);
                            $target.find('.right').css('background-color',
                                    opts.progressColor);

                            var $rotate = $target.find('.rotate');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $rotate.css({
                                    'transition' : 'transform ' + opts.duration
                                            + 'ms linear',
                                    'transform' : 'rotate(' + opts.percent
                                            * 3.6 + 'deg)'
                                });
                            }, 1);

                            if (opts.percent > 50) {
                                var animationRight = 'toggle '
                                        + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50)
                                        + 'ms step-end';
                                var animationLeft = 'toggle '
                                        + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50)
                                        + 'ms step-start';
                                $target.find('.right').css({
                                    animation : animationRight,
                                    opacity : 1
                                });
                                $target.find('.left').css({
                                    animation : animationLeft,
                                    opacity : 0
                                });
                            }
                        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.position {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pb-heading {
    border: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}


.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  color: #111;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.progress-bar div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.progress-bar div span {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    left: 12.5px;
    top: 12.5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}

.progress-bar .background { background-color: #b3cef6; }

.progress-bar .rotate {
  color: red;
  clip: rect(0 50px 200px 0); 
  background-color: #4b86db;
}

.progress-bar .left {
  clip: rect(0 50px 200px 0); 
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #b3cef6;
}

.progress-bar .right {
  clip: rect(0 50px 200px 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #4b86db;
}
 @keyframes 
toggle {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="panel db-panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading pb-heading">
                            Total Uploaded this Week
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body progress-bar-container" >
                        <div class="progress-bar position"  ng-class="rotate"  data-percent={{count}} data-duration="1000" data-color="#ccc,#f39c12"></div>
                        </div>                                                
    </div>
    <div class="panel db-panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading pb-heading">
                            Successfully Uploaded
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body progress-bar-container">
                        <div class="progress-bar position" data-percent="20" data-duration="1000" data-color="#ccc,#f39c12"></div>
                        </div>                                                
    </div>


</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that changing your progress-bar `data-percent={{count}}` to have quotes around will fix your issue:

```
<div class="progress-bar position"  ng-class="rotate"  data-percent="{{count}}" data-duration="1000" data-color="#ccc,#f39c12"></div>
```

Also I'm not sure about your logic since you didn't post any of you angularjs code, remove `ng-class="rotate"` and put just  `class="rotate"` ng-class will take expression so it will think that rotate is some property on $scope and you would need to set it up like:

`$scope.rotate='rotate'`

but using:

```
class="rotate"
```

should work fine.

Because all of this is just a workaround and messy approach, I would advise to check this and work it out AngularJS way:

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: YesI tried with data-percent="{{count}}" and it not working.

Comment: ok I updated answer with another thing I noticed - you can switch ng-class with class - but to know this for sure you would need to post your angularjs code.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention in answer is that you shouldn't use jQuery for your logic if you're using anuglarJS. Just use angularJS and rewrite your logic there it shouldn't be too hard and you will avoid having issues between AngularJS and jQuery. Anyway let me know if answer was helpful or if not I will delete it.